# INSERT return value of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to `INSERT` a `RETURN` value for a stored procedure and I just can't get it to work.

I have one table called `"person.person_ids"` with fields `"id int, uid uniqueidentifier"`

and a bunch of other tables called for example `"person.employee"`, `"person.client"` etc. These tables all get their `"id"`s as foreign keys from the `"person.person_ids"` table.

The procedure does this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PERSON.NewPerson
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ret INT;
    INSERT INTO PERSON.ID_PERSON
    VALUES (NEWID());
    SET @ret = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    RETURN @ret;
END
GO
```

and my `INSERT` looks like this:

```
    INSERT INTO PERSON.EMPLOYEE VALUES
    (EXECUTE PERSON.NewPerson, 1, '15434235', '10768348153', '1962-3-2', '1999-10-2', 'PETER', '', 'SMITH', 'HAMMER')
GO
```

Basically I'm trying to create a stored procedure of function that I can call to automatically generate a new record in `"person.person_ids"` whenever I insert a new record into `"person.employee"`.

I tried using `OUTPUT` from `INSERT` but I could not get it to work and INSERT isn't allowed inside of functions.

Comment: Instead of procedure, triggers would be a better option if you want to insert the value on some table based on insert on other dependent tables.

Comment: are your id fields int or uniqueidentifier? Because you've shown both in your SP.

Comment: @DaleBurrell the `id` field is `int` and the `uid` field is `uniqueidentifier`
@Avi I thought about it but can I return the value of a column on an inserted row?

Comment: I would create a stored procedure to `INSERT` into `ID_PERSON`, get the `identity` and then `INSERT` into `EMPLOYEE` and wrap both the `INSERT` in a `TRANSACTION`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code with the issues fixed and some recommended improvements. The comments explain what and why.

SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PERSON.NewPerson
(
  -- Use an output parameter to get values out of an SP
  @NewId INT OUT
)
AS 
BEGIN 
  -- Recommended to always list the columns you are inserting to
  -- Personally my preference is to select them (because that scales to multiple inserts), I never use the 'values' clause.
  INSERT INTO PERSON.ID_PERSON (uid)
    SELECT NEWID();

  SET @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

  -- The return statement is for a status for the SP, usually 0 for success, some other int for an error
  RETURN 0;
END
GO
```

Calling SP:

```
DECLARE @MyNewId INT;

-- Run the SP before your insert to get your new value    
EXEC PERSON.NewPerson @MyNewId OUT;

-- Then insert - ideally with a list of columns
INSERT INTO PERSON.EMPLOYEE
  SELECT @MyNewId, 1, '15434235', '10768348153', '1962-3-2', '1999-10-2', 'PETER', '', 'SMITH', 'HAMMER'
```

Comment: Can I insert multiple values using this method or only one value per insert?

Comment: I mean like `INSERT INTO PERSON.EMPLOYEE VALUES (v1,v2,v3), (v1,v2,v3), ...`

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking, but if you are asking about using `values` or `select` with your insert statement, you can do everything and more with `select` - thats why I never bother with the values option. You can put any query you like in the `select`, returning any number of records. If in doubt though, the official documentation is great.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I'm refering to what you said: That you prefer to `select them because they scale to multiple inserts`

Comment: @dominique120 - just realised you're not the OP. Well yes thats what I mean by "because that scales to multiple inserts" i.e. you can insert as many rows as are returned by the `select statement` :) (and with as many columns as are required for the insert) - its totally flexible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195034/discussion-between-dale-burrell-and-dominique120).